# HashSet Java find words according to length

Tags: java, hashset

Write a method that takes two parameters (1) the original string and (2) the word length and
returns a new string that contains the words of the specified length from the original string without
any duplicates. Here is an example of program execution:
getWordsOfLengthN(“We are the best, are we ?”, 3)  “are the”
getWordsOfLengthN(“We are the best, are we ?”, 2)  “we”
Notice that the method considers does not differentiate between the upper and lower cases.

Hint:
 Tokenize string into an array of words
 Change all the words to be become lowercase
 Store all the words into a HashSet
 Retrieve all the items from the HashSet and store them into the resulting string

I am new to java, I am taking an online course so everything I do know is self taught. I'm not sure how to go about this method, it is really stumping me. Can anyone offer me some ideas? Thanks

Comment: You should post what you have already tried and where exactly you are stuck. Since it's a Java online course, some explanation before this task is inevitable. If you missed it, you should read it.

Comment: The "hint" section pretty much tells you exactly what to do. The purpose of the HashSet is to help you remove duplicates, so that you have a collection of unique words. Your job at that point is to get all the words from the set that meet the length requirement.

Comment: Forget about coding. Sit down and on a piece of paper write out your solution in plain English, only after that should you try to translate that to code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getWordsOfLengthN(String originalString, int wordLegth) {
    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] words = originalString.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        if(word.length() == wordLegth) {
            hashSet.add(word);
        }
    }
    return hashSet.toString();
}
```